# Internet Explorer 11 Screen Reader Accessibility Issues

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, accessibility, nvda

The website i am currently building is nearly fully screen reader accessible however on one of my `<div>`'s while using Internet Explorer 11 the screen reader "NVDA" reads "Grouped" rather then the content.

The div has a tabindex of 0 and even an aria label but it is completely ignored.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you please provide the code?

Comment: Check your NVDA settings > Document Formatting and scroll to the bottom and see which Elements are checked.  I'm guessing Landmarks is not selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues that would cause this to happen. The main one that I can think of would be NVDA isn't switching over to the correct mode. This is often the case when settings are incorrect or when the code isn't semantic. However, without being able to examine your code to provide a better solution, it's hard to say. As suggested, check your settings and see if a navigation feature is turned off.

Also, keep in mind that not all screen readers behave the same way and in many cases, the developers target a specific browser. Here's a list of browser/screen reader compatibility for optimal use.

Mac:

- Safari & VoiceOver

Windows:

- Firefox & NVDA
- Chrome & NVDA (Chrome is our secondary browser with NVDA; Firefox is primary)
- IE & JAWS
- Edge & Narrator

Mobile:

- iOS: Safari & VoiceOver
- Android: Chrome & TalkBack (Firefox & TalkBack is secondary)